# xcode touchesBegan multiple tasks

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, touchesbegan

I am using touchesBegan and touchesMoved to move a UIImageView to wherever you touch on the screen. It moves a marker (the UIimageView I moved), draws a shape in the UIImageview and reads off a graph.

However whenever I try to do anything with that data eg update a label, the UIImageView scurries back to the place it started instead of staying where it is.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{

UITouch *myTouch =[[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];

int x = location.x;
int y = location.y;

NSLog(@"x = %i",x);
NSLog(@"y = %i",y);

CGPoint p={x, y};
circles.center = p;
```

The code above works fine and moves the image to its new location. However, should I add somethig really simple like

```
changeInY.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Main Label"];
```

and the UIImageView (circles) is no longer at .center = p. The label updated and the UIImageView rushed back to the place I dumped it on the storyboard before any touches were made. It definitely moves, but rushes back. Without the label instruction it stays where it is and completes the next touch.

It will give my x-position and y-postition and let me print them in an NSLog statement, but it won't let me update a label with their values, or do anything that isn't to do with that UIImageView. 
I don't want to dynamically create a UIImageView at runtime. I want to use that one and move it. 
I'm fairly sure its the circles.center = p line that needs changing, but I don't know how to tell it to make that change and stay there.

Any help would be very welcome

Comment: I have tries dozens of ways now. I've tried using a gesture recogniser with tap interceptor instead, I tried saving the values to NSUerdefaults and to a nsdictionary and using later. I tried touchesended, I tried using selectors and performing at a set time interval, I tried reframing, I tried crying, but it always always moves the image back to the original position as soon as I try to do anything at all. I can't intercept these touches and make them useful. Only move the uiimageview OR do something else.

Comment: I've tried UITouchPhaseCancelled and UITouchPhaseEnded. I tried [[self nextResponder] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; I tried [super touchesbegan]. I'm kind of grabbing at straws now.

Comment: 3 days and not a single comment. I don't think I'll be using this site again.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after about 14 hours of rewriting the code in every conceivable manner, that I just needed to place the offending label on top of a 'view' box. I had some kind of layering issue. Once the label was placed on an invisible 'View' almost every combination of code I have tried in the last two days worked.